# Correct Way to Import D3.js into an Angular 2 Application

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, typescript, angular

There are a lot of discrepancies on the correct way to import and use D3 in an Angular 2.0.0-rc.4 application. I have seen:

1) To be added to the root index.html file:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Then using:

```
Import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

in any component file that I want to implement a D3 visual in.

2) Using npm:

```
npm install d3 --save
typings install d3 --save
```

Then still using:

```
Import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

Though with TypeScript 2.0.0 Beta (if I am reading the documentation right) I can do:

```
npm install --save @types/d3
```

Then really use:

```
Import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

-- With both ways, adding the following to the `var map = { }` to the *systemjs.config.js*

```
'd3':'node_modules/d3/d3.min.js'
```

and adding to the `var packages = { }`

```
'd3':{main:'build/d3.js',defaultExtension:'js'}
```

**Can anyone confirm the correct way to implement D3? Thank you.**

Comment: Would like to know to, as my import d3 is giving me a red line "can't find module". I did the npm install d3

Comment: A slight variation of option 2 above works for me, see: https://gist.github.com/satyagraha/5544424965c41f261ac245a92673aa71

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only way that works for me is to create a file "custom-d3.ts", inside I export what I need (for example):

```
export * from 'd3-axis';
export * from 'd3-format';
export * from 'd3-interpolate';
export * from 'd3-scale';
export * from 'd3-selection';
export * from 'd3-shape';
```

And then in my other ts files I can import d3 as: `import * as d3 from '.../../custom-d3.ts'`.

I get auto completion by installing the typings `@types/d3`, and no error with typescript.

You can also use this library that does all of that for you and is injectable in your classes: https://github.com/tomwanzek/d3-ng2-service

Comment: If you are not too worried about how many d3 modules (e.g. during dev) you can just import all d3 modules with `import * as d3 from "d3";`

When going to production you will want to use the example from Oliver which is very similar to how the Angular2 team suggest to use rxjs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it but in your typings/index.d.ts file just add something like `/// <reference path="modules/d3/d3.d.ts" />.`

I didn't mess around with the systemjs.config.js and I didn't need any other import statements within the components but seemed to do the trick, I don't get any red errors.